# How to find a function in javascript files

Tags: javascript

I have many javascript files referenced in an HTML file. There is a call to function **X**. How can I find where **X** is?

---

Additional description:
It's not a local site and I don't have js, but I can download js and search the files. I'd like to use some method like Firebug, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search the [files](https://superuser.com/questions/60173/how-to-search-inside-files-in-windows-7) for X function name.  Also as previous poster said - firebug for Firefox is your special friend when developing for the web.

Comment: FWIW there's Firebug for other browsers too. :)

Comment: Firebug is great, very worthwhile.  I've seen 'developer modes' in most major browsers lately - they're catching on.

Comment: see additional description, tnx

Comment: So get it local and search - yes?  Good luck!

Comment: Efazati: Or use firebug as outlined in my solution? You said that's the kind of solution you're looking for.

Comment: some thing like LLL(x) return position

Answer (score 2):

Two methods. First, you could [grep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/) for it in your files, if you're on a Linux machine. That's probably quicker.

The other way you could do it easily is with FireBug (http://getfirebug.com). Once the page is loaded, open the console and go to the Script tag. Put the function name in the search bar and click "Next" until you find where the function is defined, and it will tell you which file it's in in the upper left hand corner.

Answer (score 0):

I would hope that if you have multiple external JS files that you have a reason for it and the functions you create in them have names that somewhat represent what they do in which you can get an idea of which file it is in.

To directly answer, open one up and use the find feature in your IDE.